Accessing .json elements via python
I'm currently struggling w/ accessing certainelements of a .json file via python.
At first, I'm retrieving the results from an API which works well:
from sp_api.api import CatalogItems
from sp_api.base import Marketplaces

def get_catalog_items(asins):
    credentials = {
        'refresh_token': 'X',
        'lwa_app_id': 'XYZY',  
        'lwa_client_secret': 'XYZT',
        'aws_access_key': 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
        'aws_secret_key': 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY'
    }

    catalog_client = CatalogItems(credentials=credentials, marketplace=Marketplaces.DE)
    for asin in asins:
        query = catalog_client.get_catalog_item(asin, includedData=["summaries, salesRanks"], marketplaceId="A1PA6795UKMFR9")
        print(query)

asins = ["B01AT3OE7M", "B01LWWJP2M", "B07D5D6628"]

get_catalog_items(asins)

The .json response looks like this (I shortened it to contain the response for one ASIN only:
{'errors': None,
 'headers': {'Server': 'Server', 'Date': 'Fri, 12 Apr 2024 09:57:47 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '845', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-rid': '5YYP1B7RX19TCPVK5HMN', 'x-amzn-RateLimit-Limit': '2.0', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '2e9fc2d9-e71d-4142-a60f-3083f4282c78', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'OPF2e9fc2d9e71d', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-6619059b-2e9fc2d9e71d4142', 'Vary': 'Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload'},
 'next_token': None,
 'pagination': None,
 'payload': {'asin': 'B01AT3OE7M',
             'ranks': [{'marketplaceId': 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
                        'ranks': [{'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/drugstore',
                                   'rank': 24,
                                   'title': 'Drogerie & Körperpflege',
                                   'value': 24},
                                  {'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/drugstore/5979638031',
                                   'rank': 2,
                                   'title': 'Molkenproteine',
                                   'value': 2}]}],
             'salesRanks': [{'marketplaceId': 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
                             'ranks': [{'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/drugstore',
                                        'rank': 24,
                                        'title': 'Drogerie & Körperpflege',
                                        'value': 24},
                                       {'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/drugstore/5979638031',
                                        'rank': 2,
                                        'title': 'Molkenproteine',
                                        'value': 2}]}],
             'summaries': [{'brandName': 'Bodylab24',
                            'browseNode': '5979638031',
                            'itemName': 'Bodylab24 Whey Protein Pulver, '
                                        'Vanille, 2kg',
                            'manufacturer': 'Bodylab24',
                            'marketplaceId': 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
                            'modelNumber': '4882',
                            'sizeName': '2 kg (1er Pack)',
                            'styleName': 'Vanille'}]},
 'rate_limit': '2.0'}

As a final step, I'd like to access certain elements by the code below, but it only works for "summaries", somehow I can't access "ranks" or "salesRanks" and I don't know why:
The error returned is always the same: "KeyError. 'salesRanks'"
from sp_api.api import CatalogItems
from sp_api.base import Marketplaces
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import time
import logging
import os

def get_catalog_items(asin_list):
    credentials = {
        'refresh_token': 'X',
        'lwa_app_id': 'XYZY',  
        'lwa_client_secret': 'XYZT',
        'aws_access_key': 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
        'aws_secret_key': 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY'
    }

    catalog_client = CatalogItems(credentials=credentials, marketplace=Marketplaces.DE)
    for asin in asin_list:
        response = catalog_client.get_catalog_item(asin, includedData=["summaries", "ranks"], marketplaceId="A1PA6795UKMFR9")
        # Extract desired information from the response
        payload = response.payload
        asin_data = {
            'asin': asin,
            'brand_name': payload['summaries'][0]['brandName'],
            'item_name': payload['summaries'][0]['itemName'],
            'manufacturer': payload['summaries'][0]['manufacturer'],
            'sales_rank_title_1': payload['salesRanks'][0]['marketplaceId'],
            'sales_rank_title_1': payload['salesRanks'][0]['ranks'][0]['title'],
            'sales_rank_value_1': payload['salesRanks'][0]['ranks'][0]['value'],
            'sales_rank_title_2': payload['salesRanks'][0]['ranks'][1]['title'],
            'sales_rank_value_2': payload['salesRanks'][0]['ranks'][1]['value'],
        }
        print(asin_data)

#short list for testing only
asin_list = ["B01AT3OE7M", "B01LWWJP2M", "B07D5D6628"]

get_catalog_items(asin_list)

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best,
Ben
I tried to make several changes to the code, including adding more extensive logging, but the only reason for errors is the KeyError. So it has to do sth with the mapping of the SalesRanks data.

The first step to solving this problem would be to validate your assumptions. After running payload = response.payload, what is the response of print(payload.keys())? Or even simply print(payload)?

You're right. I started at the very end of the problem b/c I trusted the first results coming out of the "summaries" part.
Printing the payload only shows the ranks data is not part of it, just the "summaries" data.
This means I have to check at first where the data gets lost.
Thank you very much for your help!
